# Bootstrap nav-link class is not working in Chrome, but works in Firefox, navigates to corresponding section

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am not familiar with Bootstrap, and I am trying to customize a one-page web template.
Having the sample on http://lidia.gq .
My problem is that the menu items that it has, are not workable in Chrome. So, when I click any menu item, it does nothing, when it should navigate to the corresponding section from the page. I am using Version 68.0.3440.106. 
But on other browsers like Firefox, Microsoft Edge, Internet Explorer, and on mobile Chrome I do not encounter this problem, all menu items successfully work.

So, why does it not work on Chrome Windows PC?

HTML

```
 <div class="navbar-desktop">
                <!--Navbar Brand-->
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="" /></a>
                <!--Links-->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right hidden-md-down text-uppercase">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#service">Service</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#team">Team</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#newsletter">Faq</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" target="_blank" href="#!"><i class="fa fa-search fa-lg"></i></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
```

It Uses Bootstrap  v4.0.0-alpha.2

http://lidia.gq/css/bootstrap.min.css

Maybe someone encountered the same problem? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Why are you using that alpha build of bootstrap. Update to `bootstrap@4.1.1`

Comment: Yes, Unfortunately the template I picked and already customized is using the Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.2 , I tried to updated to latest bootstrap, but it brings some unexpected changes in my site, that require more time for figuring out how to fix them.

Answer (score 1):

I did a little bit of bootstrap learning and debugging, and I figured out what was my problem, and I very happy about it. Finally I made my menu workable.

The problem is related to this top tag

```
<div class="navbar-desktop">
```

I mentioned, that I also have in my body tag:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-desktop">
```

and my html is using the `main.js`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
```

which calls the jquery

```
// localScroll js
    jQuery(".navbar-desktop").localScroll();
```

If I comment that last line (or rename), from `main.js`, my menu works. Basically, seems that this code from java script confuses my code, and instead off calling `.navbar-desktop` from bootstrap nav, it uses the one from java script.

Not sure though what this code from body tag tries to do. 
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

There's no error with your code. But I guess you have errors in calling the required source files for bootstrap.

Files needed inside `<head>` tag:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Files needed before `</body>` tag:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Your HTML code should look like this.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 <div class="navbar-desktop">
                <!--Navbar Brand-->
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="" /></a>
                <!--Links-->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right hidden-md-down text-uppercase">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#service">Service</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#team">Team</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#newsletter">Faq</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" target="_blank" href="#!"><i class="fa fa-search fa-lg"></i></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
</div>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion, but unfortunately it is not helping.